# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' and unknown column_name

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and need a quick fix for this:

```
DECLARE ColumnNamesCursor_427556864 CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName;
                                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c;
                                JOIN sys.columns sc ON  c.TABLE_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id) AND c.COLUMN_NAME = sc.Name;
                                WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'quotes';
```

> SSMS has underlined COLUMN_NAME, FROM and sc (in parentheses) for
>   syntax error

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a debugging service, questions related to syntax errors reported by the interpreter are considered as off-topic. Please read [ask], [What to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) in [help] form more info.

Answer (score 2):

You just need one semicolon ';'

```
DECLARE ColumnNamesCursor_427556864 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c JOIN sys.columns sc ON c.TABLE_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id) AND c.COLUMN_NAME = sc.Name
        WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'quotes';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the semicolon in the end of the statement

```
DECLARE ColumnNamesCursor_427556864 CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
                            JOIN sys.columns sc ON  c.TABLE_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id) AND c.COLUMN_NAME = sc.Name
                            WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'quotes';
```